# Custom links.task for secondary tab loses primary tabs

Tags: views, 9

I created a Views page and wanted to place it as a secondary task (tab) under admin/content.

I added an entry to my custom module's links.task like this:

```
mycustom.admin_orphaned_pages:
  title: Orphaned pages
  route_name: view.orphaned_pages.page_1
  parent_id: system.admin_content
```

and this works to now add a secondary task under the Admin Content page.

The issue is, when I go to this page, it loses the primary (and therefore other secondary) tabs. Is there something missing here?

Answer (score -1):

I assume your configuration here is:

1. The system.admin_content path is '/admin/content'
2. Your view's path is something **not** '/admin/content/{your path}'

=> when you access '/admin/content', '/admin/comment' you will see your tab, but when you enter {your path}, the tabs content disapeared.

**Quick fix**: change your view path to '/admin/content/{your path}' (must include the system.admin_content path as parent here)

Known issue for quick fix: Because your links.task.yml define 'parent_id: system.admin_content' as parent_id, when you access '/admin/content/{your path}, both /admin/content and '/admin/content/{your path} will be set as active.

**=> Completed fix**:

- set the path in your view to '/admin/content/{your path}' (or the path if you override system.admin_content path + /{your path})
- change 'parent_id: system.admin_content' to 'base_route: system.admin_content'

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes, View path is set to /admin/content/orphaned (I assume this would not show up at all on Content page if that was not the case). So I think all of what you said above is basically change parent_id to base_route, correct? That does not fix it (it only changes my page to go to Primary tasks - i think the view does that on its own), and still, when on the page, no pri/sec tasks show.

Comment: Hmm.. and now it works.

Comment: If it works, please update the things you made it done. Maybe someone will need it later on. @liquidcms

Comment: Not sure what made it start working. I have what i posted above in the original post.